# Will an HDMI interface work?

Tags: hdmi, kvm-virtualization

I currently have Ubuntu 12.04 but plan to upgrade to the newest version. I have an HP Pavilion a1310n that is about 10 years old. It runs fine and I am hoping to get the last year or two out of it. Does anyone know if I can get an HDMI interface card working with Ubuntu in this PC? What problems am I most likely to run into? I see there have been problems with sound. fyi, I also have a Windows PC and plan to use a KVM switch to connect to my acer H233H monitor, etc.

Comment: The easiest way to find out is to burn a 16.04 or 16.10 or whatever iso on a DVD or USB drive and boot a live session from that. This way you can check whether your hardware is compatible or not without installing anything to your disks.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my own question. I did a search on HDMI cards and found that, at least for the one I consider desirable, they require more power than my PC can provide. I am withdrawing the question.

Comment: You can get low-power GPUs that won't require upgrading your PSU.